# Jenkins Python ImportError for Twython

Tags: python, bash, jenkins

I'm trying to run a python script in jenkins, but I repeatedly get build errors saying that it can't find the Twython module. The script works fine at the command line.

I've added the same PYTHONPATH and PATH to my global variables and tried adding it in a bash script that kicks of my python script.

Twython was installed with pip.

The exact failure is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tweet.py", line 2, in <module>
    from twython import Twython
ImportError: No module named twython
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: is it the same `user` run the script? can you add a debug line into the python script say print out `which python`

Comment: I don't know what that means. I did add `pip install twython` and now it seems to work. I'm not sure that's the best option, though.